# SLDS styles not being applied to Preview mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I am beginning to make a simple app and I am using SLDS. When I preview the app from the Developer Console, the SLDS styles are not being applied. But if I put the component on a Lightning Community the styles are applied.

Lightning App:

```
<aura:application>
    <c:DownloadComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

Download Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" >

<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical-stretch slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-3">
            buttons
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-3">
            buttons
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-3">
            buttons
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Preview:
[image]

Lightning Community:
[image]

Do I need to import SLDS for only previewing it through the developer console?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can include Lightning at the application level:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:DownloadComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

This way, you don't need to have your component import SLDS only for previewing.

Comment: Perfect! @sfdcfox

Comment: Is there any reasoning as to why this happens?

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano the default app doesn't include slds. This lets you include your own style, e.g. bootstrap. If you want SLDS, you have to "ask" for it.

Comment: Adding extends=”force:slds” did not work for me - what else can I try? @JavierGarcíaManzano

Comment: This worked for me as usual. Thanks @sfdcfox! You are a saviour!